# Django filter icontains - find matches going the other way

Tags: python, django

In the code below, Django's icontains filter finds matches where the user_input is contained within the name. How do I find matches where the name is contained within the user_input?

```
names = "Jim", "Bob", "James"
user_input = "Jimbo"

Names.objects.filter(names__icontains=user_input)
#returns empty queryset

Names.objects.filter(???=user_input)
#returns queryset with "Jim"
```

Comment: Nevermind, I can get what I need to using the in filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`Names.objects.filter(user_input__in=names)`

Comment: Thanks, but I got using Names.objects.filter(names__in=user_input)

Comment: Suppose that this works too. Mine would make more sense IMO as you want to look if the user_input appears in names, right? :)